# Android Studio cwac-camera CameraFragment java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I am having a head-banging issue... I started android developing again, after 2 years pause and moved to Android Studio.

I am making a simple camera app to take a single photo.. after facing enormous issues with the preview size, orientation and rotation I decided to use cwac-camera.

I have included the library like this:

```
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
```

Using this repository:

```
maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
```

My app sdk params are:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

I have salvaged the demo project and now I am facing the following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: com.test.testapp.TestCameraFragment
```

This happens when my activity calls:

```
current = TestCameraFragment.newInstance(false);
```

upon onCreate...

I have no idea what is causing the error. I have tried cleaning, re-including the library, renaming methods, etc.

Any fresh ideas?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment` added a `getHost()` method in API Level 23 (though I think it may have existed in API Levels 21-22, just marked with `@hide`). This conflicts with the `getHost()` method in `CameraFragment`.

The workaround is to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 19 or lower, which (for some reason) does not trigger the problem.

As this is a breaking change to the public API of a discontinued library, I will need to ponder exactly what I'm going to do about it...

Comment: That fixed everything. I have replaced the compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and the appcompat library to revision of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0. Wonderful work btw.

Comment: @iganev: BTW, 0.7.0 of CWAC-Camera fixes this by renaming `getHost()` to `getCameraHost()` and `setHost()` to `setCameraHost()`. That will require some refactoring in projects using this library, but it's less risky than relying upon v19 stuff. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown#from-anything-to-070.

Comment: Thank you very much for the provided information. I will keep that in mind. I already refactored my test app to accommodate v19, so this would be useful in any future projects.